# using orWhere() in collection

Tags: laravel

I've been looking for the same functionality of eloquent `orWhere()` but in collection. I just found that I can chain multiple `where()` but I haven't found something like `orWhere()`.

So basically the question is, is there a way to achieve something like `orWhere()` in collections?

Comment: Eloquent's `orWhere("a","=","b")` simply adds an `OR a = b` to the query but does not actually execute the query. The collection `where` actively iterates through the collection matching the appropriate values. `filter` is your best bet

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have 2 solutions for this:

- Use `->filter` & add your own conditions
- Make it in 2 steps using the `->where()` then use `->merge` to
  make the final collection